# Looping in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops

I would like to run a query with variables as such:

```
SET @m = '102', @s = 'A';

call XQRY(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `schema`.`table` n WHERE n.seg = "',@m,@s,'";'));
```

I would like to loop through the select statement with @s = 'A' then @s = 'C' then @s = 'G'...

Is there a way to create an array of sorts within MySQL like @s = 'A,C,G,M,P' and have the query run for each variable in the array?

**Edit 1**

I actually have a table that has a column called 'segment' in which each record is identified by one of many segments. The segments are coded with 7 characters the same (time/date coded) and the eighth through the end characters define the particular segment (A-Z) the record is in. Depending on the need, I want to be able to run a couple queries that will split that segment into two parts. Sometimes it's one segment, sometimes it's 20 segments I need to split up. I'd like to be able to list out the segments to be split and then have the queries run through the list. (Queries already written.)

Comment: i think we can use n.seg in ().
select * from table where n.seg in (<list of values>). or you can go for a stored proc.

Comment: I'm actually going to do more than a simple select and therefore the <list of values> will not work for me.  It's a grand idea. Thank you!

Comment: what is it that you want to do (your desired result). maybe UNION instead of loop?

Comment: I actually have a table that has a column called 'segment' in which each record is identified by one of many segments. The segments are coded with 7 characters the same (time/date coded) and the eighth through the end characters define the particular segment (A-Z) the record is in. Depending on the need, I want to be able to run a couple queries that will split that segment into two parts. Sometimes it's one segment, sometimes it's 20 segments I need to split up. I'd like to be able to list out the segments to be split and then have the queries run through the list. (Queries already written.)

Comment: can you sqlfiddle.com your data and show desired result? maybe there's a way to do it in 1 Query.